# How to enable visualization of kubelet call stack on perf profile?

Tags: linux, kubernetes, linux-kernel, perf, flamegraph

I'm trying to do root-cause analysis for an issue. The cpu perf profile looks like this-
[image: CPU profile]

Apparently, more time is used by kubelet and dockerd. But the stack below has [unknown] symbols. How can I enable visualization of entire stack so as to find the go-routines cpu spends time on?

**Update 1:**
Following @coderanger's suggestion I did build binaries manually using - make all GOLDFLAGS=""

And still I am missing some symbols with perf profiling- 
[image]

Any help appreciated!

Comment: How did you install Kubernetes? https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/build/root/Makefile#L67-L85 indicated most builds run with -w, so you would probably need to make your own build.

Comment: @jww as said elsewhere, we keep K8s questions here to avoid splitting the community. Also asking about how to work with debugging symbols is very much a programming question.

Comment: @coderanger - you need to get the site rules changed. Otherwise, I am going to follow the site's rules.

Comment: @jww: questions about `perf`, profiling, and flamegraphs, are close enough to programming: those tools are pretty much never used outside of programming tasks.  Therefore the existing site rules allow this, under the "*unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.*" clause in the link you linked.  That's why SO has `perf` and `flamegraph` tags, and the questions are about *using* perf and profiling tools, not writing them or using their APIs.